# How do I determine if my Macbook pro has switchable audio input?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Some audio ports on Apple computers are switchable from stereo output to stereo input, but not all of them are.

How do I determine if my Macbook Pro supports audio input through the audio jack?

Comment: I might be wrong but to me its a switchable when you only have one Jack on the Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list specifically which audio devices your system is using in Terminal:

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType
```

Another way you can determine if you have the combination audio port is when you're viewing `System Preferences > Sound` you will have an output option that shows up on the input tab.

[image]